# How to use multiple collection with meteor-pages?

Tags: pagination, meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze

I'm trying to make a multiple collection example to work but unfortunately it doesn't. I've got data1 and data2 collection to show on "/data1/page/1" and "/data2/page/1" respectively. Only data2 collection appears on both pages. Any ideas?

Here's the codes:
https://github.com/ianpogi5/meteor-pages/tree/master/examples/multi-collection

Comment: So, do I understand correctly that you want to use data from 2 collections on one "page"?

Comment: No. They are on a different page. The first collection appears on the link "/data1/page/1" while the second collection appears on the link "/data2/page/1". You can checkout the codes from github to see what I mean.

Comment: I submitted a pull-request that added a couple examples of working with multiple collections. I finally had a chance to come back and dig in a little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across this package recently, and started implementing today. I ran into the same issue. As far as I can tell...

The predefined template `_pagesNavCont` uses the object `pagesData` to construct the page links. When you initialize the `data1` pagination object, `pagesData` corresponds to the path for `data1`. Unfortunately, whatever is initialized last (in this case `data2`) determines the data in `pagesData` for the `_pages*` templates.

I would imagine that you'd need to either hack the original code, or define your own templates for `_pagesNavCont`, `_pagesPageCont`, and `_pagesItemDefault` for one of the collections.

I've forked the code, and am going to continue looking into the issue.

Comment: I thought the package already supports multiple collection and there was something wrong with my example code. How did you go with your fork?

Comment: After some more time with it today, and coming to the conclusion that it doesn't seem to support multiple collections per page out of the box...I decided to put off using it for now. If I get a chance in the near future to play some more, I'll keep you posted.